# How to use MQTT on Arduino which uses serial com to send AT commands to ESP8266

Tags: mqtt, esp8266

I just started looking into MQTT protocol.

**Situation**

In my college project, currently, I use Arduino as main MCU and do every work in that and use Serial Comm. to send AT commands to esp8266 (for HTTP requests, to run scripts on server etc). I basically needed to push some data(from Arduino) on a webpage(hosted by a local server). I searched and found about **MQTT** protocol which enables to publish and subscribe data on clients(Exactly what I wanted). But most of the tutorials I am finding are either entirely on Arduino(with wifi shield) or entirely on esp8266.

What I want to know is that is there a possible way to use MQTT as with my current configuration? That is, using Arduino to do all the work and by using its serial comm. Publishing data just by AT commands on MQTT.

Additional Information about my project is mentioned here : [Confused about which technology to use in Smart Home System](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/confused-about-which-technology-to-use-in-smart-home-system)

Comment: You can send MQTT over wifi between Arduino and ESP. No need to do the physical connection.

Comment: for that I'd be needing wifi on Arduino too isn't it? 
I don't need to send data between Arduino and ESP. 
I am using esp for sending data from arduino to local server, my arduino doesnt have a wifi shield

Comment: Aha, if you have the physical connection already done just look at the FW ESP Easy, which have a pretty solid MQTT integration out of the box.

Comment: https://sonyarouje.com/2016/03/15/mqtt-communication-with-arduino-using-esp8266-esp-01/
I found this post, Is it what you were saying :P Is it the way to go ? Sorry I am just super newb :D

Comment: Yeah kinda. I would go with the full out ESP approach since Arduino is bulky in most cases. The ESP is in most cases a equally good candidate.

Comment: The MQTT lib for Arduino uses the Client Ardino class for TCP/IP connection. You have to replace this class with your own that uses AP command controlled esp8266.

Comment: I tried MQTT over UART(to send AT commands to esp8266) https://github.com/nopnop2002/MQTT_UNO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found [a tutorial by Sony Arouje](https://sonyarouje.com/2016/03/15/mqtt-communication-with-arduino-using-esp8266-esp-01/). As it turns out I had to completely abandon manual sending of esp commands and had to use the library (WiFiEsp.h). Hint...It's better!

Though initially it didn't work with my esp8266 because it had an older firmware and reported error "firmware not supported". I had to flash a newer Firmware (works with version 1.54 in my case). Anyone having problem flashing firmware may find some help referring this topic: [Can't Flash ESP8266 latest firmware, says "Fast Flashing error" and "Invalid head of packet(' ')"](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/cant-flash-esp8266-latest-firmware-says-fast-flashing-error-and-invalid-hea)

Also, I have saved a copy of all download tools and the tutorial page itself, so if in the future, the post is removed or if anyone doesn't finds the tools to flash. Get to me in comments or something (not posting here because I don't know if it's ok to post someone else's content)